# PHP Error Notice Show

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
    $base_url='https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
} else {
    $base_url= 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
?>
```

I write this code in my index page . and all other page i use as

```
<?php print''.$base_url.''; ?>/Views/Patient/patientList.php
```

But when I run my web site the show a notice

Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in C:\xampp\htdocs\dopatient\index.php on line 6

Comment: Now it works Without Any Error

Comment: You should accept an answer then. Or: if you found a different solution, add your own answer and accept that. This way you will positively contribute to the stackexchange network.. (yay you!)

Answer (score 0):

Use to properly check for the index' existance:

```
$base_url = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

(or alternatively:

```
$base_url = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https://' : 'http://' );
$base_url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

)

You need to check for the "on" value, since `_SERVER['HTTPS']` can be 'off' aswell. See the HTTPS bit on: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php